# Accessory View in View which gets loaded by Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a different View Controller with an AccessoryView (over the Keyboard with Icons & a Text Field). I want to load this Views over a Container View.

When I load them the Accessory View doesn't show up. If I load a View Controller with a AccessoryView alone it works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to set the FirstRepsonder

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Done! Thx